# Scroll through text div horizontally on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anime.js

I'm using `anime.js` to get a text block to parallax scroll horizontally, relative to the vertical scroll position. At the moment, I'm trying to get the relative scroll completion percentage like so  -

```
var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
horizontal = $('#horizontal'),
d = $(document).height(),
c = $(this).height();
scrollPercent = 100 * (s / (d - c));
```

Then, I'm trying to set the scrollLeft for the overflowing text div like so

`var scrollPos = scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - horizontal.width());
horizontal.scrollLeft = scrollPos`

I'm not sure how to proceed with this further. Ideally, I would want to avoid `jQuery` as well, since I'm using `anime.js` for all the other animations.

Comment: Any chance of some HTML to accompany this?

Comment: It's just a div with horizontal as the id.

Comment: I was intrigued and made a pen with your code, maybe not exactly what you wanted as animation is hard to describe without visuals: https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/aEzvoG?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks! This is quite close to what I wanted. I'll modify it myself :)